# Is anyone still making Game Boy-style 2-bit monochrome screens?

Tags: game-development, video-game-console

Whenever I see retro-style portable DIY consoles, they either use a Nokia-style 1-bit black-and-white monochrome screen like in the [Gamebuino](http://gamebuino.com/), or they're built with an RGB color screen like with the [PiGRRL Zero](https://learn.adafruit.com/pigrrl-zero/overview). I'd really like to know if anyone is still making monochrome screens in more than just 1-bit black-and-white. I mean, is that even a thing? Or are the gray tones of grayscale-capable monochrome screens controlled elsewhere in hardware?

Comment: Not sure where exactly in the internet to ask this. I know it's even sort of a silly curiosity, as tiny color LCDs are super cheap to get on Alibaba, but still.

Comment: Not that refresh would be high enough for gaming, but e-ink displays are kinda what you're looking for, right?

Comment: Well there's those high res, greyscale medical screens by companies like barco, but I'm PRETTY sure those arn't what you're looking for either

Comment: Oh, those are very nice! But no, I mean just really cheap tiny LCDs that you would find in an old cell phone, just instead of color, they allow you to display a range of grays, not just black or white.